# how could i change the value, named bytecnt

Tags: extjs4

```
items: [{
    rowspan:3,
    columnWidth: 0.5,
    margin: '10 10 10 10',
    xtype: 'fieldset',
    title:'SMS',
    enableKeyEvents: true,
    items: [{
        xtype:'textarea',
        width: 200,
        height: 160,
        id: 'content',
        value: '',
        enableKeyEvents: true,
        listeners: {
            keyup: function(form, e) {
            var cnt2;
            var len2;
            var han2;
            var varCont;
            len2 = 0;
            han2 = 0;
            varCont = this.value;

            for( cnt2 = 0 ; cnt2 < varCont.length; cnt2++ ){
                if( varCont.charCodeAt(cnt2) > 255 ){
                    len2 += 2;
                    han2 += 2;
                }else{
                    len2 ++;
                }
            }
            Ext.getCmp('bytecnt').setValue(len2);  //here is problem 
            }//keyup
        }//listener

    },{
        xtype:'text',
        html:"<input id='bytecnt' name='bytecnt' width='20' value='1'>",
        width: 200,
        height:20
    }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ext.getCmp() is for looking up components by ID. Since your input field is not a component (but rather, the HTML of a component), but just an HTML element, you could use Ext.get() to retrieve it. But remember, since the input field you're retrieving with Ext.get() isn't a component, setValue() also won't work.

Why, though, are you using xtype: text with an HTML configuration of an text input field? Why not just use xtype: 'textfield' and allow Ext JS to manage that stuff for you? You can still configure everything else you need on it, but then be able to interact with it as a component.

Comment: Thanks very much for your comment. But I have to make sentence... like "you have entered 80 byte"   ... is there any solution?